# Can you enter a Stargate from the back?

Tags: stargate

My question is this: everyone is always seen entering the Stargate from the side the kawoosh comes out. What if you entered the Stargate from the side opposite this? Would you be disintegrated, would you exit the Stargate on the other side, or would you exit the Stargate from the “normal” side-the side the kawoosh comes out?

My question is not the same as “What happens to objects that enter a Stargate from the destination side?”-I am asking about entering from the back side of the outgoing wormhole, not entering the incoming wormhole.